# Query populating dates

Tags: sql, oracle, collections

query that generates records to hold a future calculated value.

Hi I trying to write a query with the tables below to populate a collection.   I want the t2 values when the dates match but when there is not a match I want the dates to populate with a null values (will be populate later with a calculated value)  The number of records for the same date should match the last time the dates matched.  So in the example for each day after 7/1 there should be 3 records for each day and after 7/5 just 2.  I am trying to do this in one query but I am not sure it is possible.  Any help on creating this and getting into a collection would be much appreciated.

```
create table t1 as 
  WITH DATA AS
     (SELECT to_date('07/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY') date1,
    to_date('07/10/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY') date2
  FROM dual
  )
SELECT date1+LEVEL-1 the_date,
      TO_CHAR(date1+LEVEL-1, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') day
FROM DATA
WHERE TO_CHAR(date1+LEVEL-1, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
     NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date2-date1+1

create table t2 
(cdate  date,
camount number);

insert into t2 values
('01-JUL-2019', 10);
insert into t2 values
('01-JUL-2019', 20);
insert into t2 values
('01-JUL-2019', 30);

insert into t2 values
('05-JUL-19', 50);
insert into t2 values
('05-JUL-19', 20);

expected results:
01-JUL-19   10
01-JUL-19   20   
01-JUL-19   30
02-JUL-19   null
02-JUL-19   null
02-JUL-19   null
03-JUL-19   null
03-JUL-19   null
03-JUL-19   null
04-JUL-19   null
04-JUL-19   null
04-JUL-19   null
05-JUL-19   50  
05-JUL-19   20  
08-JUL-19   null
08-JUL-19   null
09-JUL-19   null
09-JUL-19   null
10-JUL-19   null
10-JUL-19   null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to this kind of problem is to build the result set incrementally in a few steps:

1. Count matches that each `THE_DATE` in `T1` has in `T2`.
2. Apply the rule you outlined in the question to those `THE_DATE` which have zero matches (carry forward (across dates in ascending order) the number of matches of the last `THE_DATE` that did have matches.
3. Generate the extra rows in `T1` for the `THE_DATE` that have zero matches. (e.g. If it is supposed to have three null records, duplicate up to this number)
4. Outer join to `T2` to get the `CAMOUNT` where it is available.

Here's an example (The three named subfactors corresponding to steps 1,2,3 above):

```
WITH DATE_MATCH_COUNT AS (
    SELECT T1.THE_DATE,
        COUNT(T2.CDATE) AS MATCH_COUNT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY T1.THE_DATE ASC) AS ROWKEY
    FROM T1
             LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
    ON T1.THE_DATE = T2.CDATE
    GROUP BY T1.THE_DATE),
    ADJUSTED_MATCH_COUNT AS (
        SELECT THE_DATE,
            MATCH_COUNT AS ACTUAL_MATCH_COUNT,
            GREATEST(MATCH_COUNT,
                     (SELECT MAX(MATCH_COUNT) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ROWKEY ASC )
                      FROM DATE_MATCH_COUNT SCALAR_MATCH_COUNT
                      WHERE SCALAR_MATCH_COUNT.ROWKEY <= DATE_MATCH_COUNT.ROWKEY AND
                          SCALAR_MATCH_COUNT.MATCH_COUNT > 0)) AS FORCED_MATCH_COUNT
        FROM DATE_MATCH_COUNT),
    GENERATED_MATCH_ROW AS (
        SELECT THE_DATE, FORCED_MATCH_COUNT, MATCH_KEY
        FROM ADJUSTED_MATCH_COUNT CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEVEL AS MATCH_KEY
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DECODE(ACTUAL_MATCH_COUNT,0,FORCED_MATCH_COUNT,1)))
SELECT THE_DATE, CAMOUNT
FROM GENERATED_MATCH_ROW
         LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
ON GENERATED_MATCH_ROW.THE_DATE = T2.CDATE
ORDER BY THE_DATE, CAMOUNT ASC;
```

Result:

```
    THE_DATE    CAMOUNT
____________ __________
01-JUL-19            10
01-JUL-19            20
01-JUL-19            30
02-JUL-19
02-JUL-19
02-JUL-19
03-JUL-19
03-JUL-19
03-JUL-19
04-JUL-19
04-JUL-19
04-JUL-19
05-JUL-19            20
05-JUL-19            50
08-JUL-19
08-JUL-19
09-JUL-19
09-JUL-19
10-JUL-19
10-JUL-19
```